# categories and sub-categories in grails

Tags: grails

I am trying to add category and subcategories to currently logged in User(which is organization). I can add category to User(Organization) but not able to add subcategories.

Associations:

```
Organization hasMany = [follows: SubCategory]
Category hasMany = [ subCategories: SubCategory ]
SubCategory belongsTo = [ category: Category]
```

**Category and subcategories Structure:**

```
Main Category
 Sub Category
 Sub Category
 Sub Category

Main Category
 Sub Category
 Sub Category
 Sub Category

Main Category
 Sub Category
 Sub Category
 Sub Category
```

**Note: When I select any main category, it takes me a list of subcategories related to this category and I want to select and add those subCategories to Organization.**

**Organization.groovy**

```
class Organization extends Party{

    String orgName
    Person contact
    String orgSize
    boolean isVendor  = false

  static hasMany = [follows: SubCategory]

  static constraints = {
    orgName blank: false
    orgSize blank: false
  }
}
```

**Category.groovy**

```
class Category {

    String name
    String description

    static constraints = {
        subCategories nullable:true
    }

    static hasMany = [ subCategories: SubCategory ]
}
```

**SubCategory.groovy**

```
class SubCategory {
    String name 

    static hasMany = [requirements: Enquiry]
    static belongsTo = [ category: Category]
    static constraints = {
        requirements nullable:true
    }
}
```

**OrganizationController.groovy**

```
class OrganizationController {

  def saltSource
  def userCache
  def springSecurityService
  def mailService
  def messageSource
  def organizationService
  def subscriberService
  static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

  def index() {
    redirect(action: "list", params: params)
  }

    def list() {
      params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)
      [organizationInstanceList: Organization.list(params), organizationInstanceTotal: Organization.count()]
    }

    def profile() {
      Subscriber loggedinSubscriber = subscriberService.getLoggedinSubscriber()
      Party organization = loggedinSubscriber?.customer?.party
      Party person = organization?.contact
      [orgInstance: organization, personInstance: person]
    }

    def update() {
      def orgInstance = organizationService.getOrganization(params.id)
      orgInstance.properties = params
      orgInstance?.contact?.properties = params
      println params
      try {
          organizationService.updateOrganization(orgInstance)
      }
      catch ( CustomValidationException e){
          flash.message = e.sMessage
      }
      catch (ServiceException s ) {
          flash.message = s.message
      }
     render(view: "_org", model: [orgInstance: orgInstance])
  }

    def follow() {
      Subscriber loggedinSubscriber = subscriberService.getLoggedinSubscriber()
      Party organization = loggedinSubscriber?.customer?.party
      def subparams = params.subcategories
      println subparams
      def marketInstance = Category.get(params.abc)
      def subMarket = getsubCategories(params.subcategories)
      def follower = new Follower()
      follower.followedBy = organization
      follower.category = marketInstance
      follower.subCategory = subMarket
      follower.save(failOnError: true);
      flash.msg = "Okay. This market is now on your watchlist."
      redirect (action: "profile")
    }
}
```

Follow action in above controller is responsible for adding category and subcategories to Organization(User).I tried with following code

def subMarket = getsubCategories(params.subcategories)
 follower.subCategory = subMarket

in follow action but getting

```
No signature of method: com.vproc.member.OrganizationController.getsubCategories() is applicable for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.String;) values: [[2, 1, 3]] error.
```

subCategory.gsp

```
<g:form  controller="organization" params="[temp : marketInstance?.id]" action="follow" method="post">
                <g:hiddenField name="id" name= "abc" value="${marketInstance?.id}"  />
                <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${subcategory?.id}" />
                  <div style="margin-left:200px">
                    <input type="button" class="button-inner" id="check1" value="Check All" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="isChkd" value="true" />
                    <g:each var="subcategory" in="${subCategroyInstanceList}">
                    <div>
                    <g:checkBox class="cb1-element" name="subcategories" value="${subcategory.id}"/>
                    <label for="subcategories"> ${subcategory.name}</label>
                    </div>
                  </g:each>
                  <button class="btn btn-inverse">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </g:form>
```

**Problem:**
How to get selected subcategories and add them to Organization using follow action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already using the same `name` to all your checkboxes, so in you controller you can transform it in a list:

```
def sub = params.list('subcategories')
sub.each { id ->
   ... //add to your organization.
}
```

This is the list of id's that you need to associate with your `Organization`, so if you're updating you probably need to remove those that already are associated and aren't present in the list before adding the new ones.

Comment: hi @sergio-michels thanks for your reply. I tried with your suggestion     def sub = params.list('subcategories')
        sub.each { id ->
           follower.subCategory = sub
} but I am getting error like argument type mismatch in line follower.subCategory = sub . Any suggestion on this.

Comment: You have only the id, so you need to get the Subcategory instance before adding to the list.

Comment: To make it more clear: `follower.addToSubCategories(SubCategory.get(id))`

Comment: hi @sergio-michels , when I tried with                            def sub =   params.list('subcategories')
        sub.each { id ->
       follower.addToSubCategories(SubCategory.get(sub))
      }  . It gives error "Provided id of the wrong type for class com.vproc.market.SubCategory. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList" . Any suggestion what I am doing wrong.

Comment: hi @sergio-michels , I even tried with follower.addToSubCategories(SubCategory.get(id)). This is also not working.

Comment: static constraints = {
        subCategories nullable:true
    }
i think,No need of this in category domain.Remove this first.

Comment: def sub = params.list('subcategories')first check u can get the list of ids.

Comment: then, sub.each{def subIns = SubCategory.get(it) pritnln subIns}.check this.

Comment: then add this to the follower.sub.each{def subIns = SubCategory.get(it) follower.addToSubCategories(subIns) }follwer.save(flush:true)

Comment: by doing this, we can find where the problem is. acoording to that we can proceed.

Comment: hi @Anantha , I tried with def sub = params.list('subcategories'). It gives me output like [1,2]. This seems valid.

Comment: hi @Anantha when I tried with    def sub = params.list('subcategories')
      sub.each{def subIns = SubClass
    groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
Message
    No such property: subIns for class: com.vproc.member.OrganizationControllerory.get(it) pritnln subIns}. It throws error like

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40291/discussion-between-vieenay-and-anantha)